# Connection to db using php in localhost

Tags: php, mysql, database, localhost

Even if I have used LAMPP many times, this time something goes wrong. When I visit the browser(chrome) nothing echos. Here is my code:

**index.php**

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); /*after edit*/
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysqli_close($link);

?>
```

Do I miss something? The output is nothing. By the way i write my files in

> var/www/html/my_pages

and i call it this way: `localhost/my_pages`. Simple echos are working and php in general is fine. Something goes wrong with my db connection.

Comment: Is error reporting on? Can you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the start of your code and try again?

Comment: what is your error??

Comment: @scosu I tried this "error_reporting(E_ALL);" but nothing is printed.

Comment: did you get error in browser if you open this?

Comment: @SubinThomas I see no errors

Comment: is your site root correct in your site config?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On');` before `error_reporting(E_ALL);`.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois It worked. Now I can see my "Fatal Error:Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/diamond/index.php on line 8"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the response! I found the problem. Something went wrong and mysqli wasn't enabled in php. That's why i had this error `Fatal Error:Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/diamond/index.php on line 8` I reinstalled php and problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'db');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
}
else
{
echo 'Connected successfully';
}
?>
```

Comment: This is how exactly i have written my code the first time. None of the prints worked. Do you think that the problem is in "mysqli_connect" ? And if so why there are no errors?

Comment: because you have used:- error_reporting(E_ALL) :-- this will hide all error and worning

Comment: @Anand how does it hide them? Check the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) please.

Answer (score 0):

Yes probably, because mysqli_connect() method return the object, not Boolean value. 
You can verify the connection with the following code:

```
if($link->connect_error) 
     die('Connect Error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . ') '. mysqli_connect_error());

return false;
}
else{
echo "Connection Successful";
   return $link;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not using PDO.

```
 $dsn = "mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db";
        try {
        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, "root", "");
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
            $ex->getMessage();
        }
```

with PDO you can change anytime you need the Db vendor:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
echo phpinfo();
?>
```

Run this file and get all PHP and apache details. Search for mysqli support in it. If it is supported, you should have something like below.
[image]

Also check for your root directory [image]