# How To Turn database Connection And. Important Functions In Mysqli

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

This Is My Database configuration 
It's Extension is Mysql. iwant to change its extension to Mysqli. Help me please.Thanks In Advance.I Want to Change This Because MySQL EXTENSION is no longer available in latest php
class CMySQL {

```
// variables
var $sDbName;
var $sDbUser;
var $sDbPass;

var $vLink;

// constructor
function CMySQL() {
    $this->sDbName = 'YOUR_DB_NAME';
    $this->sDbUser = 'DB_USER_NAME';
    $this->sDbPass = 'DB_USER_PASS';

    // create db link
    $this->vLink = mysql_connect("localhost", $this->sDbUser, $this->sDbPass);

    //select the database
    mysql_select_db($this->sDbName, $this->vLink);

    mysql_query("SET names UTF8");
}

// return one value result
function getOne($query, $index = 0) {
    if (! $query)
        return false;
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    if ($res && mysql_num_rows($res))
        $arr_res = mysql_fetch_array($res);
    if (count($arr_res))
        return $arr_res[$index];
    else
        return false;
}

// executing sql
function res($query, $error_checking = true) {
    if(!$query)
        return false;
    $res = mysql_query($query, $this->vLink);
    if (!$res)
        $this->error('Database query error', false, $query);
    return $res;
}

// return table of records as result in pairs
function getPairs($query, $sFieldKey, $sFieldValue, $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    if (! $query)
        return array();

    $res = $this->res($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    if ($res) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $arr_res[$row[$sFieldKey]] = $row[$sFieldValue];
        }
        mysql_free_result($res);
    }
    return $arr_res;
}

// return table of records as result
function getAll($query, $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    if (! $query)
        return array();

    if ($arr_type != MYSQL_ASSOC && $arr_type != MYSQL_NUM && $arr_type != MYSQL_BOTH)
        $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC;

    $res = $this->res($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    if ($res) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, $arr_type))
            $arr_res[] = $row;
        mysql_free_result($res);
    }
    return $arr_res;
}

// return one row result
function getRow($query, $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC) {
    if(!$query)
        return array();
    if($arr_type != MYSQL_ASSOC && $arr_type != MYSQL_NUM && $arr_type != MYSQL_BOTH)
        $arr_type = MYSQL_ASSOC;
    $res = $this->res ($query);
    $arr_res = array();
    if($res && mysql_num_rows($res)) {
        $arr_res = mysql_fetch_array($res, $arr_type);
        mysql_free_result($res);
    }
    return $arr_res;
}

// escape
function escape($s) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($s);
}

// get last id
function lastId() {
    return mysql_insert_id($this->vLink);
}

// display errors
function error($text, $isForceErrorChecking = false, $sSqlQuery = '') {
    echo $text; exit;
}
```

}

$GLOBALS['MySQL'] = new CMySQL();

Comment: Do you have mysqli installed??

Comment: Just Wamp Server..would it need any separate Installation??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368572/connection-to-db-using-php-in-localhost/32369238#32369238  refer this and there it is given how to check mysqli installed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysqli has object oriented approach to all the funtions. 
for example,

```
$this->vLink = new mysqli("localhost", $this->sDbUser, $this->sDbPass,$this->sDbName);
```

But along with the object oriented approach mysqli procedural approach also exists which has just mysqli instead of mysql everywhere. But I personally recommend you to go with the object oriented approach.
you can see other important functions along with the old mysql functions [here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp).